# Query quotes in execute statement

Tags: oracle

I have this correct query (I am getting the value from a procedure, my problem is with the quotes):

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into TABLES (table_name)
  values ('||''''||TABLE_NAME||''''||')');
```

When I try to add another column, I get an error, can anybody add the correct quotes? This one is incorrect:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into TABLES (table_name,column_name)
  values ('||''''||TABLE_NAME||''''||'',''||column_name||''''||')');
```

Comment: There is no need to use native dynamic sql(`execute immediate` statement), use static, simple `insert into` statement. 2) Do not just say you are getting an error, provide the error message as well.

Comment: If you do have to use dynamic SQL (and you don't for this example) it's useful to put the command into a string variable so you can use `dbms_output` to display it - then you can see exactly what is being executed, which make debugging much easier. You should also use bind variables.

Answer (score 2):

For the statement you have:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into TABLES (table_name,column_name)
  values ('''||TABLE_NAME||''','''||column_name||''')');
```

But you should use bind variables, which are much easier to construct and read as well as much safer:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into TABLES (table_name,column_name)
  values (:table_name,:column_name)') USING TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;
```

And as noted in comments this doesn't need to be dynamic at all; or at least it wouldn't if you had called your variables something different to the column names - which still works but looks ambiguous:

```
insert into TABLES (table_name,column_name)
values (TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME);
```

You can specify the scope to make things clerarer; assuming your procedure is called `MY_PROC` you can do:

```
insert into TABLES (table_name,column_name)
values (MY_PROC.TABLE_NAME,MY_PROC.COLUMN_NAME);
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you even need dynamic sql - I don't know the context in which you're attempting this - your quotes problem would be sorted as follows:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into TABLES (table_name) values ('''||TABLE_NAME||''')');

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into TABLES (table_name,column_name) values ('''||TABLE_NAME||''','''||column_name||''')');
```

But really you should be using bind variables:

```
declare v_table_name varchar2(30); 

begin

    -- get your v_table_name here

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('insert into TABLES (table_name) values (:TABLE_NAME)')
    USING v_table_name;

end;
```